# Flask Debugger not working under Windows

Tags: python, debugging, flask

I am a newbie to Python attempting to experiment with sample code under Windows 8.1.

On http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/ it  says "if you enable debug support the server will reload itself on code changes, and it will also provide you with a helpful debugger".

I have added to the code `app.run(debug=True)` to the sample code on the above page. The server will now reload itself on code changes (as promised) but when I create a syntax error the "helpful debugger" does not show. Instead I get an error message in my command prompt.

Any ideas why? I suspect the answer might be here [Can't enable debug mode in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552231/cant-enable-debug-mode-in-flask) but it is largely uninteligible to me.

So far I have tried restarting my machine and putting the code in different locations. I am not in a forked environment (as best as I know). For those that are curious my source code is shown below:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
app.wsgi_app = DebuggedApplication(app.wsgi_app, True)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World! #note the deliberate syntax error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger is for debugging exceptions in a syntactically valid program. Try raising an exception in your code, visit the URL in a browser window, and you will see the very helpful debugger. See also http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/21/

Syntax errors will be shown on the console as you have seen. That's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users

The page and resource that was selected as the answer in this post led to a broken page. However, try the code below.

Set debug mode using

```
$env:FLASK_ENV = "development"
```

Run app

```
flask run
```

[This post solved it for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65899307/11737951)

Or

Set it directly from the app in your code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000)
```