# How to disable HTTP response debug?

Tags: python, logging, python-requests, werkzeug

My python code is currently printing the following line to the logs at the conclusion of every REST API call (high-level info on the response it is sending back):

```
111.111.111.111 - - [15/Aug/2017:12:03:15 +0000] "POST /some_endpoint 
HTTP/1.1" 202 72 "-" "python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/3.4.3 Linux/3.13.0-83-generic"
```

Through other searches I've seen the following suggestions on how to get rid of it:

1) `logging.getLogger('werkzeug').setLevel(logging.ERROR)`

2) `logging.getLogger('werkzeug').disabled = True`

3) Same as above, but `requests` instead of `werkzeug`

These have no effect.  Another solution offered up was to use a completely different stream for logging but that's not going to be an option for my needs.

This is obviously getting logged through a separate mechanism than the rest of my logs since the format is different, but I can't seem to pinpoint the culprit.

Comment: Is this flask? How do you start the app? Maybe you started it in debug mode.. Also have a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552231/cant-enable-debug-mode-in-flask). It might help.

Comment: Also, please consider marking code as code, even if it is a log message. That helps reading your question, in my opinion.

Comment: edit to OP is pending @rocksteady

Comment: @rocksteady Yes, this is flask.  Have verified this log statement exists both with and without DEBUG mode enabled at that level.  (And thanks for the the tip on marking as code -- forgot that when I posted).

Comment: Looks pretty now :)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can find the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) instance in any library and adjust the logging level

You can access the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html) utility via [`werkzeug._internal`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/_internal.py)

```
from werkzeug._internal import _logger
```

then I adjust the root logger to [`logging.CRITICAL`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-levels) (which is `50`)

```
_logger.setLevel(50)
```

This means that [`Werkzeug`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) will only print `CRITICAL` (or higher) output

You can then adjust the `_logger` level according got your needs

## Direct example

This applies to your example by searching for the `import logging` command in the [`Werkzeug`](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug) github page. This I found in `werkzeug._internal` then we can do

```
In [2]: from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
   ...:
   ...: @Request.application
   ...: def application(request):
   ...:     return Response('Hello World!')
   ...:

In [3]: from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

In [4]: run_simple('localhost', 4000, application)
 * Running on http://localhost:4000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

In [5]: from werkzeug import _internal

In [6]: _internal._log('info', 'Setting logger level to Critical!')  # see below why this is required
Out[6]: 'Setting logger level to Critical!'

In [7]: _internal._logger.setLevel(50)

In [7]: run_simple('localhost', 4000, application)
```

In the case the `_logger is None` then this occurs because no `Werkzeug` logging instance has been called. See [line 75](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/_internal.py#L75) in `_internal` for more clarity

```
In [1]: from werkzeug import _internal

In [2]: type(_internal._logger)
Out[2]: NoneType

In [3]: _internal._log('info', 'removing logger!')
removing logger!

In [4]: type(_internal._logger)
Out[4]: logging.Logger
```

Comment: I suppose, the OP describes server side logging. Your answer, however, shows a way to modify the client side request, namely the requests module, logging Messages.

Comment: So I tried using `requests.logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)` but I am still seeing the HTTP response debug line being printed out.  Will investigate the possibility of the root logging level being set to DEBUG (though, as mentioned in an above comment, I have tried this in the past with that set higher with no effect).

Comment: I see you are using `werkzeug` - I will adjust

Comment: @ChrisTwichell I'll remove the `requests` references in a sec I just added the `Werkzeug` bit directly first so yuo can play with it

Comment: So when I try to access `werkzeug` directly I get the following exception:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setLevel'`

Had keyed in on `werkzeug` possibly being what was printing out the debug statement based on other SO searches that showed the exact same formatted messages I'm seeing.

Comment: Maybe we can tackle this a different way...  The debug statement that I'm trying to get rid of is formatted with an IP address followed by something followed by a timestamp and other things.  But what follows the timestamp is blank -- is that supposed to be the logger name?

Comment: can you not do `from werkzeug._internal import _logger`

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Yes I can execute that step, but it appears that `_logger` comes back as `None` (hence the NoneType exception).

Comment: @ChrisTwichell that is occuring because you haven't yet ran any Werkzeug functions. See github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/… On this line the _logger is only initiated after the first logger call - I have adjusted my answer to cover your case